# Ajax Call Confusion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

before we start apologies for the wording and lack of understanding - I am completely new to this.

I am hoping to run a php script using Ajax - I don't need to send any data to the php script, I simply need it to run on button press, after the script is run I need to refresh the body of the page. What I have so far:
HMTL Button with on click:

```
<a href="#" class="button" onclick = "AjaxCall()"><font color = "white">Next Question</font></a>
```

JS Ajax call:

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'increment.php',
        type: 'php',
        success:function(content,code)
        {
            alert(code);
            $('body').html(content);
        }
    });        
}
```

this runs the php script but doesn't stay on the current page or refresh the body - has anyone got any ideas - apologies if this is completely wrong I'm learning - slowly.

Many thanks in advance.

**As a small edit - I don't want a user to navigate away from the page during the process

Comment: Why are you even using AJAX? Why not just go to that page?

Comment: ^because Im loading an object at the start of my page - im trying to run increment to increment a counter to change contents within the boad hence why I need the body to reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ajax should be

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'increment.php',
        type: 'post',
        success:function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $('body').html(data);
        }
    });        
}
```

if you want to learn ajax then you should refer [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

and if you just want to load that page then you can use  `.load()`  method as "Dutchie432" described.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `load` instead of the typical `ajax` function?

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $(body).load('increment.php');
}
```

Additionally, if you were to use the `ajax` function, `php` is not a valid type. The `type` option specifies whether you are using GET or POST to post the request.

As far as the `dataType` option (which is what I think you mean), The Ajax doesn't care what technology the called process is using (like ASP or PHP), it only care about the format of the returned data, so appropriate types are `html`, `json`, etc...

Read More: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Furthermore, if you are replacing the entire body content, why don't you just refresh the page?

Comment: ^ I really apologise for the next question -> would I put this within my JS <script> tags

Comment: Yes, it would replace the content of your `AjaxCall` function. See Update.

Comment: I cant use load as this navigates away from the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AjaxCall() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="button" onclick = "AjaxCall()"><font color = "white">Next Question</font></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can study about js and ajax here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp will help a lot. Of course all js functions if called from internal js script should be inside `<script></script>` and if called from external you call the js gile like `<script src"somejs.js"></script>` and inside js there is no need for `<script>` tags again. Now all those function do not work by simply declaring them. So this:

```
function sayHello(){
    alert("Happy coding");
}
```

doesn't work because it is just declared and not called into action. So in jQuery that you use after we declare some functions as the sayHello above we use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    sayHello();
});
```

Doing this we say that when everything is fully loaded so our DOM has its final shape then let the games begin, make some DOM manipulations etc

Above also you don't specify the type of your call meaning `POST` or `GET`. Those verbs are the alpha and omega of http requests. Typically we use `GET` to bring data like in your case here and `POST` to send some data for storage to the server. A very common `GET` request is this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type     : 'GET',
        url      : someURL,
        data     : mydata, //optional if you want to send sth to the server like a user's id and get only that specific user's info
        success  : function(data) { 
            console.log("Ajax rocks");
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Ajax failed");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to fire a javascript event in this way there are two ways to go about it and keep it from actually trying to follow the link:

```
<a href="#" class="button" onclick = "AjaxCall(); return false;"><font color = "white">Next Question</font></a>
```

Note the `return false;`. This stops the following of the link. The other method would be:

```
<a href="javascript:AjaxCall();" class="button"><font color = "white">Next Question</font></a>
```

Note how this actually modifies the href to be a javascript call.